# The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch (version 7.10.2 ) with python (django version 3.0) but I am getting this error

`The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch`

While searching on the internet I found that downgrading the version of elastic search from 7.14 is was working for a lot of people as version 7.14 was updating a few internal scripts. But in my case the version is already lower than 7.14.

I used `curl -X GET "HTTP://localhost:9200"` to check its version.
Also, other such issues included NODE, Angular and other frameworks which were not relevant to my case.

How can I solve this issue? If I need to downgrade then which version am I supposed to downgrade?

Comment: Take a look at your elasticsearch server version. Then read the [compatability section of the elasticsearch docs](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.3.3/#compatibility) for what version of the client is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work with a python client version less than 7, but in my case it was quite an old version of Elasticsearch.

I've solved it with `pip install -U 'elasticsearch<7'` which installed version `6.8.2`.

I'll try and update both Elasticsearch and the python client and get back with more details.

Comment: Had same issue on elasticsearch==7.14.0.  Downgrading to elasticsearch==7.10.0 worked for me.